# Deploy a Git Branch to Node Server for Testing

Tags: git, node.js

This is my first post here, so apologies if this question has already been answered.

We're working on a project using Git and Node and they're both new to me. I have a Node server on my own computer which is currently running what's in the master branch in Git.

To make some changes in our code, I checked out my local branch and committed some changes. Now, my question is **what must I do to refresh these changes in Node without having to merge to master?** I'd like to test these changes in my browser before merging to the master branch. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can't you just test from w/e branch you committed on locally? If all works, you can push to master, pull on the node server, and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch update to date information from a remote repository you simply need to:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will pull all the up to date information from the origin remote, including any new branches you have not synced with the system yet.  Now just switch to the branch that you want to use.

```
git checkout -b someBranch origin/someBranch
```

Note the first someBranch can be anything you want.  You don't have to name your branches the same as remote.  Git keeps up a file of references of local branch names, vs remote branch names.  But it is certainly idiomatic to name local branches after remote branches.